# Getting Matrix to work on IE8 Filters

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, transform

I am working on a project where I have created arrow ends on a navbar.  The problem is transforms don't work on IE8 or below, so I wanted to implement the filter css for IE to make it behave, however, I can't get it to function properly.  The object doesn't rotate 45 like the matrix is telling it to.  I don't know if there is something else in the code preventing it from rotating or what.  I would appreciate any feedback concerning how to fix this problem.

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:before {
    background: #3b679e; 
    background: linear-gradient(left top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #3b679e 0%, #2b88d9 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); 
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#3b679e), color-stop(50%,#2b88d9), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); 
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); 
        background: -o-linear-gradient(left top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); 
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(left top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);  
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    border-radius:0 8px 0 0;
    content: ' ';
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067811865474, M12=-0.7071067811865477, M21=0.7071067811865477, M22=0.7071067811865474, SizingMethod='auto expand');
    height: 27px;
    margin-left:-34px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -sand-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: 28px;
}
```

I have tried to use the polyfills of transformie and cssSandpaper and they don't work on correcting this either. The rotate is applied on the .navbar .nav > li > a:before rule.

http://jsfiddle.net/rsxavior/sTP5F/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why this doesn't work and I am posting for future reference in case someone runs into the same problem.  IE8 will not apply the matrix to psuedo classes such as :before and :after.  I needed to add an empty span tag within the a element and change the margin for this to work as intended.